# Ruby Regex for repeated numbers in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, computer-science

If i have a string like `"123123123"` - Here `123` is repeated 3 times.

1. So how can i get only `"123"` in ruby?

2. So if the string is `"12312312"` - Here `123` is repeated 2 times and then just `12`, so here still i need to get `"123"`.

3. Even if string is `99123123123`, still i need to get `123`.

Is this possible in Ruby Regex?

EDIT: I want this to solve [Project Euler Problem 26](https://projecteuler.net/problem=26) . So here `123` can be anything. All i want is to extract 1 number of at-least 2 repeated numbers.

Comment: No not possible in any regex as I think 123 is dynamic not static 123, you better write a program in ruby to fix it... not a direct/indirect regex solvable problem

Comment: What is minimum length of repeating group?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question - Please check!

Comment: you should better not solve those kind of questions with string manipulations. do some math, and believe me, it will be easier.

Comment: How will this help you solve the exercise?

Comment: @marmeladze , Yes you're right. Things didn't worked out like i thought. After so much thinking in this way - i searched on google and I finally did it from [here](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2010/07/21/project-euler-26-ruby/)

Comment: @SagarPandya, i thought i'll save all the repeated numbers in an array and loop through that array to find maximum count(as this is string - string.count) of all the elements. There are many problems <br> 1. I didn't read the question properly, 2. Regex way doesn't work. I found solution [here](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2010/07/21/project-euler-26-ruby/)

Comment: @AdityaNagla you should try to find a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will detect all repeating groups.

`(\d+)(?=.*\1)`

[Demo](https://regexr.com/3kd04)

Works great with ruby too.

```
result = '9912341234123'.scan(/(\d+)(?=.*\1)/)
#gets group with largest length
longestRepeatingGroup = result.max_by{|arr| arr[0].length}

puts longestRepeatingGroup
puts longestRepeatingGroup[0].length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
99123123123.scan(/123/).count
12312312.scan(/123/).count
```