# Regular expression to match a string with a repeating pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to find a regex that matches URLs with three or more repeating segments (and may include any number of directories) such as:

- `s1 = 'http://www.foo.com/bar/bar/bar/'`
- `s2 = 'http://www.foo.com/baz/biz/baz/biz/baz/biz/etc'`
- `s3 = '/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/'`

and not match URLs like:

- `s4 = '/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/barbaz'`

First I tried:

```
re1 = /((.+\/)+)\1\1/
```

which works:

```
re1 === s1 #=> true
re1 === s2 #=> true
```

but as the number of segments grows, the regex match takes exponentially longer:

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  (10..15).each do |num|
    str = '/foo/bar' * num
    puts str
    b.report("#{num} repeats:") { /((.+\/)+)\1\1/ === str }
  end
end

       user     system      total        real
/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
    10 repeats:  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.054839)
    /foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
    11 repeats:  0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.213492)
    /foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
    12 repeats:  0.870000   0.000000   0.870000 (  0.871879)
    /foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
    13 repeats:  3.370000   0.010000   3.380000 (  3.399224)
    /foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
    14 repeats: 13.580000   0.110000  13.690000 ( 13.790675)
    /foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
    15 repeats: 54.090000   0.210000  54.300000 ( 54.562672)
```

Then, I tried a regex similar to one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48657171/1020168):

```
re2 = /(\/.+)(?=.*\1)\1\1/
```

which doesn't have performance issues, and matches the strings I'd like to to match:

```
re2 === s3 #=> true
```

but also matches strings I don't want it to match, such as:

```
re2 === s4 #=> true, but should be false
```

I'm close with the second regex. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.` to `[^\/]`. This should decrease the complexity of the regex since it won't be trying to match "any" character.

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |b|
  (10..15).each do |num|
    str = '/foo/bar' * num
    puts str
    b.report("#{num} repeats:") { /(([^\/]+\/)+)\1\1/ === str }
  end
end

10 repeats:  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000015)
/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
11 repeats:  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
12 repeats:  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
13 repeats:  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
14 repeats:  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar
15 repeats:  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000005)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Definitions**

Suppose:

```
str = 'http://www.example.com/dog/baz/biz/baz/biz/baz/biz/cat/'
```

We can define `'/dog'`, `'/baz'`, `'/biz'` and so on as *segments*. A *group* is comprised of one or more contiguous segments, such as `'/dog'`, `'/baz'`, `'/dog/baz'`, `'/baz'`, `'/baz/biz'`, `'biz/baz'`, `'/baz/biz/baz'` and so on.

**The Problem**

It is my understanding that the problem is to determine if a given string contains three (or more) contiguous and equal groups followed by a forward slash. `s2` meets this test with the following substring:

```
'/baz/biz/baz/biz/baz/biz/'
```

**Algorithm**

I do not believe a single regular expression can be fashioned to make this determination, but we can write a regular expression to determine if at least three (or some arbitrary number) of contiguous, equal groups are present, *given* the number of segments per group. Suppose this is done by a method named `contiguous_fixed_group_size?`, which, is called as follows:

```
contiguous_fixed_group_size?(str, segments_per_group, nbr_groups)
```

and returns `true` or `false`. To ensure that the string has at least 3 contiguous, equal groups (for a given value of `segments_per_group`), we call this method with `nbr_groups = 3`. I think it best to briefly postpone the construction of this method; for the present just assume it is available to us.

The approach I've taken is to call this method with different values of `segments_per_group` and determine if the method returns `true` for at least one of those values.

**Main method**

The first step is to determine the number of segments in the string (where `str` holds the string given above):

```
 r = /(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)/
 nbr_segments = str.scan(r).size - 1 
   #=> 8
```

We may document this regular expression by writing it in *free-spacing* mode:

```
 r = /
     (?<!\/)  # match is not to be preceded by '/' (negative lookbehind)
     \/       # march '/' 
     (?!\/)   # match is not to be followed by '/' (negative lookahead)
     /x
```

The *lookarounds* prevent `'//'` in `str` from being matched.

We now ask ourselves what is the maximum value of `segments_per_group` that we must consider. As we require that:

```
nbr_groups * segments_per_group <= nbr_segments
```

it follows that:

```
segments_per_group <= nbr_segments/nbr_groups
```

where integer arithmetic is employed on the right. For `nbr_groups = 3`, we obtain:

```
segments_per_group <= 8/3 => 2
```

We therefore may determine if `str` contains (at least) `nbr_groups` contiguous, equal groups as follows:

```
(1..nbr_segments/nbr_groups).any? do |segs_per_group|
  contiguous_fixed_group_size?(str, segs_per_group, nbr_groups)
end
  #=> true
```

We may wrap this in a method:

```
def contiguous?(str, nbr_groups)
  nbr_segments = str.scan(/(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)/).size - 1
  (1..nbr_segments/nbr_groups).any? do |segs_per_grp|
    contiguous_fixed_group_size?(str, segs_per_grp, nbr_groups)
  end
end
```

**Constructing the method `contiguous_fixed_group_size?`**

This method may be written as follows:

```
def contiguous_fixed_group_size?(str, segments_per_group, nbr_groups)
  r = /((?:\/[^\/]+){#{segments_per_group}})\1{#{nbr_groups-1}}/ 
  str.match?(r)
end
```

For

```
str = s2
segments_per_group = 2
nbr_groups = 3
```

the regular expression is:

```
r #=> /((?:\/[^\/]+){2})\1{2}\//
```

Here it is written in *free-spacing mode*:

```
r = /
    (?<!\/)                    # match is not to be preceded by a forward slash
                               # (negative lookbehind)    
    (                          # begin capture group 1
      (?:                      # begin non-capture group
        \/[^\/]+               # match '/' followed by 1+ char other than '/'
      )                        # end non-capture group 
      {#{segments_per_group}}  # execute non-capture group segments_per_group times
    )                          # end capture group 1
    \1{#{nbr_groups-1}}        # execute contents of capture group 1
                               # nbr_groups-1 times 
    \/                         # match '/'
    /x                         # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

**Examples**

`str` as defined above.

```
contiguous?(str, 3) #=> true
contiguous?(str, 2) #=> true
contiguous?(str, 1) #=> true
contiguous?(str, 4) #=> false
```

```
str = 'http://www.example.com/dog/baz/biz/baz/bix/baz/biz/cat/'
contiguous?(str, 3) #=> false
contiguous?(str, 2) #=> false
contiguous?(str, 1) #=> true
```